# Reading FTP File with Android

Tags: android, file, networking, ftp, download

I am using FTP to upload a file. This works great. This file contains information what the app should do.
So I am doing the following:
1) Download the file with Apache FTP Client (seems to work fine)
2) Try to read out the file with a BufferedReader and FileReader.

The problem:
I get a NullPointerException while reading the file. I guess that this is a timing problem.

The code has this structure:

```
 ...
    getFile().execute();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(...);
```

How can I solve this problem? 
I have to use a seperate Thread (AsyncTask) to download the file because otherwise it will throw a NetworkOnMainThread Exception.
But how can I wait until the file is completely downloaded without freezing the UI? 
I cannot use the BufferedReader inside AsyncTask because I use GUI elements and I have to run the interactions on the GUI Thread, but I have no access to it from AsyncTask. RunOnUiThread does not work as well because I am inside a BroadcastReceiver.

Some code:

```
  private class GetTask extends AsyncTask{
  public GetTask(){
  }
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
              try {
                client.connect("*****");
            }
            catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                try {
                    client.login("*****", "*****");
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/"+userID+".task" );
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                resultOk &= client.retrieveFile( userID+".task", fos );
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

         try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }/**
            try {
                client.deleteFile(userID+".task");
            }
            catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            **/
            try {
                client.disconnect();
            }
            catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }




            return null;

        }

    }
```

The Broadcastreceiver class:

```
 public class LiveAction extends BroadcastReceiver {
 ...
private Context cont;
FileReader fr = null;
BufferedReader br;

@Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
    cont = context;
...
    new GetTask().execute();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {
        fr = new FileReader("/sdcard/"+userID+".task");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
            br = new BufferedReader(fr)
        String strline = "";
        try {

            while ((strline = br.readLine()) != null){
                            if(strline.equals("taskone")){
                            //Some GUI Tasks
                            }
            ....
```

This is the relevant code.

Comment: Please provide more code it is hard to guess what the situation is. At least something like the whole BroadcastReceiver! Is the BroadcastReceiver a class or an inner class or just new BroadcastReceiver(){...}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to read the file's contents from the doInBackground inside the AsyncTask and then output an object which contains the info you need on the onPostExecute method of the async stask and then manipulate your UI.

```
private AsyncTask<String,Void,FileInfo> getFile(){
      return new AsyncTask<String,Void,FileInfo>{
            protected FileInfo doInBackground(String url){
                 FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(); // FileInfo is a custom object that you need to define that has all the stuff that you need from the file you just downloaded
                 // Fill the custom file info object with the stuff you need from the file
                 return finfo;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(FileInfo finfo) {
                // Manipulate UI with contents of file info
            }

      };
}


getFile().execute();
```

Another option is to call another AsyncTask from onPostExecute that does the file parsing but I would not recommend it

Comment: Is it possible change the UI in onPostExecute? It does not work in doInBackground.

Comment: Thank you. I did not expect that it is so easy. =)

Answer (score 0):

I would try some thing like this:

```
private class GetTask extends AsyncTask{
    LiveAction liveAction;
    public GetTask(LiveAction liveAction){
        this.liveAction = liveAction;
    }
    ...  
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        liveAction.heyImDoneWithdownloading();             
    }
}
```

Ps: why the Thread.sleep(5000)?

```
public class LiveAction extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ...
    public void heyImDoneWithdownloading(){
        //all the things you want to do on the ui thread
    }
}
```